# SQL aggregate with multiple rows

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate

I have the following query

```
SELECT tagindex, AVG(val) from floatTable
 WHERE tagindex IN(828,856,883,910)
   AND DateAndTime > DATEADD(HH,-1,GETDATE()) 
   AND DateAndTime < DATEADD(HH,-2,GETDATE())
group by tagindex
```

It returns the following:

```
828   1
856   1
883   1
910   1
```

How can I return a single result where it is the combined average of all the rows?

Comment: When you say "the combined average of all the rows", do you mean the rows from floatTable, or the rows in the result set you show? @RedFilter's answer gives you the former, @Jeremy's answer the latter. I should add that the latter seems statistically highly suspect - averaging averages is rarely the right thing to do.

Comment: RedFilter provided what I was looking for. I guess I need to get back to the basics :)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT AVG(val) 
FROM floatTable 
WHERE tagindex IN (828, 856, 883, 910) 
    AND DateAndTime > DATEADD(HH, -1, GETDATE()) 
    AND DateAndTime < DATEADD(HH, -2, GETDATE())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Avg(AverageValue)
From
(
   SELECT tagindex, AVG(val) as AverageValue from floatTable
   WHERE tagindex IN(828,856,883,910)
   AND DateAndTime > DATEADD(HH,-1,GETDATE()) AND DateAndTime < DATEADD(HH,-2,GETDATE())
   group by tagindex
) AverageValues
```